# How to integrate OpenLayers with Elm.Land

Tags: openlayers, elm

I'm using [ElmLand's web component example](https://elm.land/guide/working-with-js.html) as a guide to building a web component for OpenLayers having created a project using the site's introduction.

The app runs in localhost with a silent console window.
But no OpenLayers map is appearing on the page. Just the earlier example "Say, hello" Button.

I've added a `node` to the `Home_.elm` `view`:

```
view : Model -> View Msg
view model =
    { title = "Homepage"
    , body =
        [ Html.button [ Html.Events.onClick UserClickedButton ]
            [ Html.text "Say, hello" ]
        , Html.node "map" [] []
        ]
    }
```

I've copied `ol.css` from `node_modules/ol` into ElmLand's `static` directory.
My component is defined in `ol-map.js`:

```
import '../../static/ol.css'
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM'
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile'
import { Map, View } from 'ol'
import { fromLonLat } from 'ol/proj'

window.customElements.define('ol-map', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        const map = new Map({
            target: 'ol-map', // also tried target: this
            layers: [
                new TileLayer({
                    source: new OSM(),
                }),
            ],
            view: new View({
                center: fromLonLat([0, 0]),
                zoom: 2,
            }),
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("map initialising: ", map, map.isRendered())
        }, 5000)
    }
})
```

`Main.css`:

```
@import './ol.css';

body {
    padding: 32px;
    height: 100%;
}

#ol-map {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And:

I've not edited `interop.js` since adding the previous example's `OPEN_WINDOW_DIALOG` code.

Browser Network pane reports status 200 for all the files downloaded including `ol-map.js`, `ol.css`, `ol_source_OSM.js`, `ol_layer_Tile.js`, `ol.js`, `ol_proj.js` and various names beginning with `chunk-*.js`.

I added a `console.log` (see code, above) and it does print to the console when I open the page at http://localhost:1234/

It's output of map{} includes:

```
loaded_ : true
maxTilesLoading_ : 16
ol_uid : "5"
values_ : {layergroup: LayerGroup, target: 'ol-map', view: View}
```

and `isRendered()` outputs false.

It all looks in order. But no map is displayed.
I've tried integrating `three.js` as Elm Land's working with JS example and that worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

The string in `Html.node` needs to match the string in `customElements.define` for it to recognise the custom element.

You need to change `Html.node "map"` to `Html.node "ol-map"`.

Also, AFAIK the `target: 'map'` line should really be `target: this`, as you are not looking up an element with the `id="map"`, but rather the custom element you just created.

Comment: thanks; I changed to `Html.node: ol-map` and tried both `target: this` and `target: "ol-map"` but the map remained unrendered. I added another `Html.button` after `Html.node` and found that the two buttons were displayed horizontally without a gap between them when I tried `target: "ol-map"` but vertically when I tried `target this`

Answer (score 1):

One needs to create an element, attached to the custom element for the OpenLayers code to target:

```
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM'
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile'
import { Map as MapElement, View } from 'ol'
import { fromLonLat } from 'ol/proj'


class OpenLayersElement extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super()
    }

    async connectedCallback() {
        // element required for OpenLayers to target
        const div = document.createElement('div')
        div.id = 'map'
        this.appendChild(div)

        // Create an OpenLayers map inside the custom element
        const map = new MapElement({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [
                new TileLayer({
                    source: new OSM(),
                }),
            ],
            view: new View({
                center: fromLonLat([0, 0]),
                zoom: 2,
            }),
        });
    }
}

window.customElements.define('ol-map', OpenLayersElement)
```